Trying compile darknet with CMake but fail

Operating System: Windows 10
CUDA : 11.8
cudnn: 11.8
CMake: 3.30
Visual Studio: 2022
darknet: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

My CMake can't find my CUDA, but I use nvcc --version can get information.
CMD response
CMake Error
And I go to CMakeLists.txt:118
CMakeList.txt
I search all the file didn't see where variable CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER is.
Can someone help me how to fix this problem.
I have add CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER to environment variable but still no work.
And I have try uninstall all the programs then install them back, also no use.

Stack Overflow discourages using images for represent textual information. This is noted in the [ask] and in that question on meta. Instead, copy paste the code and the error message directly into the question post.

The repo you are attempting to use has been abandoned for several years now.
The correct modern Darknet/YOLO repo to use is this one:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents
You'll find (I hope?) the build instructions for Windows have been greatly simplified.  Of importance, the Mac, Linux, and Windows instructions are now more-or-less exactly the same on all 3 platforms.
Of importance to you, the cmake files were re-written to use the modern methods of detecting CUDA and cuDNN, as well as OpenCV to make things simpler.
You can find the Windows build instructions in the readme:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet?tab=readme-ov-file#windows-cmake-method

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I have been stuck in this problem for a week. I will try your advice!
